# Cannot add bitmapdata to group - phaser

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm asking this question continuing from [How can I fix bitmapdata to the camera in Phaser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46695098/how-can-i-fix-bitmapdata-to-the-camera-in-phaser/46696512#46696512) I tried it and it worked, however I found that the bitmapdata wouldn't update. My current code:

```
bitmap = game.add.bitmapData(800, 100);
bitmapSprite = game.add.sprite(0, 0, bitmap);
bitmapSprite.fixedToCamera = true;
```

I've tried:

```
bitmap = game.add.bitmapData(800, 100);
bitmapSprite = game.add.sprite(0, 0);
bitmapSprite.addChild(bitmap);
bitmapSprite.fixedToCamera = true;
```

And:

```
bitmap = Game.add.bitmapData(800, 100);
bitmap.dirty = true;
bitmapSprite = Game.add.sprite(0, 0);
bitmapSprite.fixedToCamera = true;
var group = Game.add.group();
group.add(bitmap);
group.add(bitmapSprite);
```

This is the error I get for the first:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.children[t].updateTransform is not a function
```

This is the second error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.preUpdate is not a function
```

I am using Phaser CE v2.8.7.

EDIT:

**Found a solution:**

Whenever I want to update the bitmapdata I simply use this:

```
bitmapSprite.loadTexture(bitmapSprite)
```

You have to make sure the dirty property is set to true:

```
bitmap.dirty = true
```

Thanks.

Comment: which phaser version are you using?

Comment: Phaser CE v2.8.7.